# Getting Garbage value when converting Float to string?

Tags: c

I am getting garbage value when converting float to string. I cant use sprintf because it takes more memory and PIC24 microcontroller ram size is very low (128kb). When converting it gives some garbage values as ?39.88 like this What may be the problem . I am posting my code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
float Distance=0;
char str[15]; 
    unsigned char *ftos(float f,int precision)
{
    memset(str,0,sizeof(str));
    float ff;
    ff = f;
    int a,b,c,k,l=0,m,i=0;
    // check for negative float
    if(f<0.0)
    {
    str[i++]='-';
    f*=-1;
    }
    a=f;    // extracting whole number
    f-=a;   // extracting decimal part
    k = precision;
    // number of digits in whole number
    while(k>0)
    {
        l = pow(10.0f,k);
        m = a/l;
        if(m>0)
        {
            break;
        }
        k--;
    }
    // number of digits in whole number are k+1

    /*
    extracting most significant digit i.e. right most digit , and concatenating to string
    obtained as quotient by dividing number by 10^k where k = (number of digit -1)
    */
    for(l=k+1;l>0;l--)
    {
        b = pow(10.0f,l-1);
        c = a/b;
        str[i++]=c+48;
        a%=b;
    }
    str[i++] = '.';
    /* extracting decimal digits till precision */
    for(l=0;l<precision;l++)
    {
        f*=10.0;
        b = f;
        str[i++]=b+48;
        f-=b;
    }
    str[i]='\0';
    return str;
}
void distance(float lat1, float lon1, float lat2, float lon2)
{
    float dlon=0,dlat=0,a=0,c=0,dist=0;
    dlon = (lon2 - lon1) * (M_PI / 180.0);
    dlat = (lat2 - lat1) * (M_PI / 180.0);
    a = pow(sin(dlat/2.0), 2) + cos(lat1*(M_PI / 180.0)) * cos(lat2*(M_PI / 180.0)) * pow(sin(dlon/2.0), 2);
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
    dist = 6367 * c;
    Distance += dist;  
}
int main()
{
    distance(13.00659,80.121212,13.69898,80.256987);
    printf("%s\n",ftos(Distance,6));
}
```

when i print the distance value after conversion it gives some garbage value... why?

Comment: Well, one of the standard suggestions here is to use a debugger and check out what's going on. (Because that's precisely what I'd do if I tried to help you find an error in 100+ lines of code, absent glaring errors like missing allocations etc.)  If that's too big a hurdle (I'm not sarcastic; gdb can be somewhat inaccessible) just scatter printfs in strategical places. (Run your code on a big machine for debugging...)

Comment: So you can use `printf` but not `sprintf`? That seems unlikely as both are probably doing the same thing under the hood (and might even call the same functions for the formatting).

Comment: Drop the `distance` function and provide a simple example just using `ftos`. Like `printf("%s\n",ftos(1.4, 6));`

Comment: You use float and pow().  That's all the FP support library sucked in, right there.

Comment: 'PIC24 microcontroller ram size is very low (128kb).'  That is not low.  For a PIC, that is very high.

Comment: vertical spacing, horizontal spacing, and indenting do not make the code bigger, However, such spacing does make the code ever so much easier for us humans to read.   Suggest inserting such appropriate spacing between functions, between code blocks, etc.

Comment: strongly suggest following the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code outputs 19 warning messages about conversion to `float` from `double`.   When compiling, enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: all the literal values are `double`s.  when the code only needs `floats`  strongly suggest appending a `f` to the end of each of the literal values

Comment: the code contains several 'magic' numbers (2.0, 180.0, 63.67, 13.00659,80.121212,13.69898,80.256987, 10.0, 48, 15.   'magic' numbers clutter the code and make it much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: Since the format of a `float` is well known, why all the fiddling?   Simply extract the parts of the format. and work with those parts.

Comment: this line: `Distance += dist;` seems a bit off.  The `Distance` variable is only set in one place and only set once, so why the `+=`  why not `=`?

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to make the variable names and the function names the same spelling, with only capitalization as a difference.  BTW: you could reduce your memory foot print by having the `Distance` variable be local to the `main()` function AND by having the `distance()` function return a float value, rather than setting the global variable `Distance`.

Comment: You could reduce your memory foot print (and speed up the code) by making the calculation: `M_PI/180` only once an using the results of that calculation everywhere else.   Rather than calling `pow()`  It would be better to simply multiply (perhaps in a loop) the base value times the base value ...  this expression: `sin(dlat/2.0), 2)` is executed multiple times,  Suggest only calculate it once then use the results of that calculation

Comment: After removing `float ff;` & `ff = f;` and removing `unsigned` from ftos type, the code compiled without error.  When run it gives what appear to be correct results with no garbage characters printed. Your posted coordinates returned '78.329978'. (Not running this on a PIC)